# mysql sum returning wrong value

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sum, left-join, inner-join

Hi there so i have this problem in the following query, inside `wp_wti_like_post` i have number of rows with similar `post_id` and with `value` column as `1` or `-1`.
So let's say for post with id `727` i have only one row , so the `sum` should be `1`, but don't know why it does return `4`  and when there are `two` rows with `727` it does return `8` query is below:

```
SELECT wp_posts. * , 
       SUM( wp_wti_like_post.value ) -4 AS total_sum,
       wp_wti_like_post.post_id
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wp_posts.ID =  
                                        wp_term_relationships.object_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =  
                                   wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id ) 
JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_wti_like_post ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_wti_like_post.post_id    ) 
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN ('$c_cid')
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
HAVING SUM( wp_wti_like_post.value )  > $min_like
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Comment: "similar post_id" define similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using joins among many tables and there may b a chance that any of them has many associations for a `post_id` therefore your `sum is incorrect` i suggest you to use a sub select for your like table and calculate sum in sub select and then join with your main query

```
SELECT 
  p.*, COALESCE(l.sum_like,0) AS total_sum,
  l.post_id 
FROM
  wp_posts p 
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ttr 
    ON (p.ID = ttr.object_id) 
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt 
    ON (ttr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) 
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT post_id ,SUM(`value`) sum_like
      FROM wp_wti_like_post 
      GROUP BY post_id
  ) l ON (p.ID = l.post_id) 
WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'category' 
  AND tt.term_id IN ('21') 
  AND p.post_type = 'post' 
  AND (p.post_status = 'publish') 
HAVING total_sum > 2 
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

Also note i have removed `wp_postmeta` join because its not used in your selection criteria and neither in your filter criteria also `wp_postmeta` stores different attributes for each post so i guess this table is producing more rows thats why wrong sum is calculated.

`Removed -4 from query`

Comment: this returns 0 rows , but there are at list 20 posts with , more then 2 likes.

Comment: @repo can you provide some sample data set @[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so that will be easy for me ?

Comment: Hey , i just removed -4 and it did return , rows , let me just check if rows are right , :).

Comment: With just correction of : -4 which was my mistake , your answer works :). thanks a lot